# ¿Como puedo hacer responsive esta barra de navegación en bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
Lo que me ocurre es que al reducir el tamaño de pantalla o ponerlo en modo móvil, la barra lateral desaparece y no se ve ni se puede seleccionar nada y querría que se colapsara...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar-sticky">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">
                  <span data-feather="alert-triangle"></span> Incidencias <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="temperatures.html">
                  <span data-feather="thermometer"></span> Temperaturas
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="jsp/weather.jsp">
                  <span data-feather="cloud"></span> El tiempo
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Estimado, de que barra lateral estamos hablando? podrías agregar por favor un snippet con tu código y unas capturas de tus resultados para ayudarte?

Comment: Te falta el botón con la clase `.navbar-toggler` para colapsar el menú. Mira la documentación de dicho componente [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#toggler), si tienes alguna duda puedes editar tu pregunta mostrando el avance que has logrado.

Comment: Los avances son nulos.

Answer (score 0):

basado en el codigo que subiste he agregado lo requerido para que el menú se transforme en un icono hamburger en resoluciones menores.

El nuevo codigo es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

        <div class="sidebar1 col-3 h-100">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="border: 1px solid red;">

                <button class="boton navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="menues collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">

                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">
                                <span data-feather="alert-triangle"></span> Incidencias <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="temperatures.html">
                                <span data-feather="thermometer"></span> Temperaturas
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="jsp/weather.jsp">
                                <span data-feather="cloud"></span> El tiempo
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="col-9 bg warning">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="https://dummyimage.com/1000x400/000/fff" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

puedes ver el codigo corriendo en [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/peSsJ8aDzF).

Nota: he incluido imagen de prueba para ocupar el espacio del body y un borde rojo para indicar el sidebar.

Suerte.